# React app: redirect a page to another page

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am working on a web application using React. I'm struggling to navigate to another page. When I press the button, I can see the direction of the page change, but there is no actual change in the content of the page.

This this my code:

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
 
  const anotherPage = () => navigate("/Troubleshooting");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Button onClick={anotherPage} variant="primary">
        <Link to="/Troubleshooting"></Link>
        Get Started
      </Button>
  );
}
```

Comment: Are you rendering a router and routes to navigate to, specifically a route for `path="/troubleshooting"`? Please [edit] to include a more complete [mcve]. The code you've shared here isn't even complete and compilable.

Answer (score -1):

This should properly trigger the navigation to the "Troubleshooting" page when the "Get Started" button is clicked. If the content of the page isn't changing, ensure that the "Troubleshooting" route is correctly set up in your routing configuration

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';

function App() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const anotherPage = () => navigate("/Troubleshooting");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Button onClick={anotherPage} variant="primary">
        Get Started
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by ensuring that the route is correctly set up in routing configuration?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

The routing is correct, for the content to change when it is being navigated, you have to make sure whether you declare the 'createBrowserRouter' and add objects to that array like the below code.

```
import { createBrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/Troubleshooting",
    element: (
      <div>
        <h1>Troubleshoot component goes here</h1>
      </div>
    ),
  }]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).